Build environment variables undefined when invoking cloud function
I am trying to call a Build environment variable in my google cloud function, but it keeps returning undefined. And when I log the entire process.env I don't see my Build or Runtime environment variables. Here's my Build environment variables

And here is my cloud function:
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const { OpenAI } = require("openai");

functions.http('sendToChat', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(process.env)
  const {messages, userPhone} = req.body;
  const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
  });
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-4o-mini",
    messages: messages,
  });

  res.send(completion.choices[0].message.content);
});

And I just get this for the process.env log:
{
  HOSTNAME: '<host-name>',
  LANGUAGE: 'en_US:en',
  PWD: '/workspace',
  FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE: 'cloudevent',
  PORT: '8080',
  CNB_STACK_ID: 'google.22',
  NODE_ENV: 'production',
  CNB_GROUP_ID: '<id>',
  HOME: '/home/cnb',
  LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
  SHLVL: '0',
  CNB_USER_ID: '1000',
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/layers/google.nodejs.runtime/node/lib',
  LC_ALL: 'en_US.UTF-8',
  PATH: '<path>',
  FUNCTION_TARGET: 'sendToChat',
  _: 'node_modules/.bin/functions-framework'
}

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Instead of showing a screenshot of text, it's much better if you copy the text into the question so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  It's also probably easier than dealing with a screenshot.  Please edit the question to improve this.

@DougStevenson ive edited it

Are you following this Documentation to set environment variables. Also what do the logs show? Also have a look at the suggestion shared by @Doug in this Stackoverflow Link.

Did you try to log the envvar values? Are you sure you do not have a trailing space?

Yeah I logged the env variables and my env variable did not show. I showed the logs above. Somehow it's working in production when i trigger the endpoint from elsewhere, but when I try to test the function within the Google Cloud Run UI it gives the env var is undefined.

Runtime variables are only available while executing the function. And build env variables are available while building that functions hence Build environment variable will not be available in google cloud function scope.

I tried to replicate by following the Link and was able to deploy successfully and I was able to log the FOO_RUN=foo-run in the cloud logging.

I also get "undefined" when test-function (before deploy) in google-cloud-console. But once it's deployed I get the correct log values. Btw, you should remove OPENAI_API_KEY from build-env. Your code need it as runtime-env, not build-env.
